# Biased Asymmetric Random Walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider the random walk $S_n$ given by:
$$
S_{n+1}= 
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  S_n + 2  & \mbox{w.p } p\\
  S_n -1   & \mbox{w.p } 1-p
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
Assume that $S_0=n > 0$ with certainty. What is the probability of eventually reaching the origin (the point 0) ?

Now I know the derivation for the same problem but when it's symmetric and unbiased namely the additions are $1,-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ for each. Can I use this result or that I need to make the derivation from the start?

Comment: not clear you can reuse the same result. This walk is biased, so larger p means you will have drift; also skipping one may be a problem -- i.e. you can reach -1, and then skip over to 1 if $n<0$.

Comment: I will edit now but $n > 0$